# MYSQL php Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, mysql

I have almost figured out this problem, and have been stuck on it for hours, and have gotten to the point where I need help. I am trying to configure an API with PHP and mysql and see if I can get it to work via postman. I am also doing a few joins accross multiple tables, which may be the reason why it appears to be confusing to me.

Here is the error that I get on Postman:

```
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\API_Demo2\Models\Post.php:218
```

Here are the separate tables

```
private $table = 'company2';
private $table_Main = 'main';
private $table_Retake = 'retake';
private $table_Retake1 = 'retake1';
```

Here is the PHP code that I used to insert data:

```
$query = 
  // COMPANY2
  'INSERT INTO ' . $this->table . '
    (Company2_ID_Company2, Company2_DHS6_ID)
    VALUES(:Company2_ID_Company2, :Company2_DHS6_ID)' . 
    
    // MAIN
    'INSERT INTO ' . $this->table_Main . '
    (Company2_ID_Main, Retake_ID_Main)
    VALUES(:Company2_ID_Main, Retake_ID_Main)' . 
    
    // RETAKE
    'INSERT INTO ' . $this->table_Retake . '
    (Retake_ID, Retake1_ID)
    VALUES(:Retake_ID, :Retake1_ID)' .
    
    // RETAKE1
    'INSERT INTO ' . $this->table_Retake1 . '
    (Retake_ID_Retake1, Pass)
    VALUES(:Retake_ID_Retake1, :Pass)';
```

Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: You're missing a colon in one query, but you also seem to be stringing several queries together without a delimiting semi-colon between them. Although PDO does, apparently, support this, it makes interpreting results difficult, and does little that executing a number of separate queries won't do.

Answer (score 0):

In your second query, you have missed a colon.

```
VALUES(:Company2_ID_Main, Retake_ID_Main)
```

should be:

```
VALUES(:Company2_ID_Main, :Retake_ID_Main)
```

Comment: Thank you! I just made that fix. Now I got this error: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Comment: I can't tell what the error is from this little amount of code. Please post more if you can.

Comment: I first clean the data with a sample piece of code           $this->Company2_ID_Company2 = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->Company2_ID_Company2));

Comment: Then I bind the data:                                                        $stmt->bindParam(':Company2_ID_Company2', $this->Company2_ID_Company2);

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post the file on something like pastebin?

Comment: Finally, I get data from my post and output in in json via $data such as this:   $post->Company2_ID_Company2 = $data->Company2_ID_Company2;

Comment: Don't post code to an off-site resource. Edit the code into your question, and ensure there is enough to reproduce the problem. See [mcve]